# Expose C++ template class using Rcpp module

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am wondering if I can use a Rcpp module and expose a templated c++ class, maybe like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class vec
{
public:
  vec(T x): vec_()
  {}

  T get(size_t i)
  {
      return vec_[i];
  }

  void push_back(T d)
  {
     vec_.push_back(d);
  }

private:
   std::vector<T> vec_;
};

RCPP_MODULE(vector_module) {
  using namespace Rcpp;
  class_< vec<T> >("vec")
  .constructor()
  .method( "push_back", &vec::push_back)
  .method( "[[", &vec::get);
}
```

This doesn't compile, because of the template in the module definiton. So my question is: can this be implemented somehow? Or should I create something like a `union` for all classes of vectors I want to use, e.g.:

```
union vec_type {
 std::vector<int> ...;
 std::vector<std::string> ...;
 ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, a simple example is in RcppAnnoy.  You still need different module names (== C level) for the difference templated classes.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks :)